# php search array rule value?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I do got an array where I do want to make a search but dont know how to make it work

here are my array

```
$myarray = Array
(
    [dogname] => Array
        (
            [0] => white
            [1] => zeon
            [2] => imao
        )

    [visit] => Array
        (
            [0] => once
            [1] => twice
            [2] => twice
        )
}
```

I wanted to search where visit = twice and display dogname I used `in_array from php and array_search function` but it doesnt work out. is there other custom function that can search value from a array rule or any tips on how to able get the value from compared string.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/array_keys), which, in this case, returns an array of keys whose values match the string "*twice*":

```
$keys = array_keys($myarray['visit'], 'twice', true);
foreach($keys as $key)
{
    echo $myarray['dogname'][$key] , "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
zeon
imao
```